# Problem with Positive And Negative Button in singleshoicedialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have a bottom navigation fragment and i want to show a single choice dialog in a fragment when a button clicked but i have this logcat:

```
2020-06-24 18:47:27.954 18946-18946/app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app, PID: 18946
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void app.MapChoiceFragment$SingleChoiceListener.OnNegativeButtonClickedMap()' on a null object reference
        at app.baharestanschool.ir.MapChoiceFragment$1.onClick(MapChoiceFragment.java:55)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:174)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

here is my error's code:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final String[] item = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.addresses);
    builder.setTitle("choose")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(item, position, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    position=i;
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("O", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    mlistener.OnPosetiveButtonClickedMap(item,position);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("c", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    mlistener.OnNegativeButtonClickedMap();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: I think  `mlistener` is null

Comment: how can i give a value to `mlistener`?

Comment: What is `mListener`?

Answer (score 1):

**You should create a dialog as below:-**

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
private OnButtonClickListener mlistener;

public interface OnButtonClickListener {
     void OnPositiveButtonClickedMap(String[] item, int position);
     void OnNegativeButtonClickedMap();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        mlistener = (OnButtonClickListener) getActvity();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final String[] item = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.addresses);
    builder.setTitle("choose")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(item, position, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    position=i;
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("O", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    mlistener.OnPositiveButtonClickedMap(item,position);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("c", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    mlistener.OnNegativeButtonClickedMap();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
  }
}
```

**In your Activity, implements OnButtonClickListener as below:-**

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnButtonClickListener {

}
```

For more info click [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment)

Comment: in line `mlistener.OnPositiveButtonClickedMap(item,position);`
i have this error`Expected 0 arguments but found 2`

Comment: updated plz check. modified `OnButtonClickListener`

Comment: i read https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment

Comment: and i used your updated guid but now i have a below error

Comment: 2020-06-24 20:18:23.164 21374-21374/app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app, PID: 21374
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void app.baharestanschool.ir.MapChoiceFragment$OnButtonClickListener.OnPositiveButtonClickedMap(java.lang.String[], int)' on a null object reference

Comment: you should implement `OnButtonClickListener` in your activity

Comment: I have a fragment and i implement this `implements MapChoiceFragment.OnButtonClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own Dialog. I build my own custom Dialog With the following example [enter link description here](https://github.com/mr-shoxruxbek/beruniy-dialog/blob/master/app/src/main/java/firbase/go/beruniy/view_setup/DialogBuilder.kt)